# GraphQL clearing session cookie results to cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, express-session

I am trying to figure out how to clear an `httpOnly:true` client read-only session cookie via graphql. I am successful of `session.destroy` cookie in Redis store, however, `res.clearCookie` seems to have conflict resulting to `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

```
    logout: requiresAuth.createResolver(
      async (parent, args, { req, res }) => {
          return req.session.destroy((err) => {
              if (err) reject(err);

              res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME);
              resolve(true);
          });
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved this issue :) The logout mutation must be a promise that will be executed on the front-end to prevent the cannot set headers when clearCookie is being executed.

Back-end resolver

```
    logout: requiresAuth.createResolver((parent, args, { session, res }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);

        res.clearCookie(config.sess.name);

        resolve(true);
      });
    })),
```

Front-end

```
  logout = async () => {
    await this.props.logout();

    window.location = '/login';
  };
```